# How to resolve this error ? GUI Window tried to begin rendering while something else had not finished rendering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the only editor script in the project :

The error in the editor is not giving any script name or line number.
When I clear the error in the console window the error will show again after few seconds.

The full error message :

GUI Window tried to begin rendering while something else had not finished rendering! Either you have a recursive OnGUI rendering, or the previous OnGUI did not clean up properly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TagsAndLayers))]
public class TagsAndLayersCustomEditor : Editor
{
    string tagname = "";
    string layername = "";

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        TagsAndLayers myTarget = (TagsAndLayers)target;

        tagname = EditorGUILayout.TextField("", tagname);

        if (tagname == "" || tagname == null)
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create Tag"))
        {
            myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname);
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Remove Tag"))
        {
            myTarget.DeleteTag(tagname);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(50);

        layername = EditorGUILayout.TextField("", layername);

        if(layername == "" || layername == null)
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create Layer"))
        {
            myTarget.AddNewLayer(layername);
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Remove Layer"))
        {
            myTarget.DeleteLayer(layername);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the script is like after the changes from the solution answer :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TagsAndLayers))]
public class TagsAndLayersCustomEditor : Editor
{
    string tagname = "";
    string layername = "";

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        

        DrawDefaultInspector();
        TagsAndLayers myTarget = (TagsAndLayers)target;

        EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>  myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname);

        tagname = EditorGUILayout.TextField("", tagname);

        if (tagname == "" || tagname == null)
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create Tag"))
        {
            myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname);
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Remove Tag"))
        {
            myTarget.DeleteTag(tagname);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(50);

        layername = EditorGUILayout.TextField("", layername);

        if(layername == "" || layername == null)
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create Layer"))
        {
            myTarget.AddNewLayer(layername);
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Remove Layer"))
        {
            myTarget.DeleteLayer(layername);
        }
    }
}
```

I added the line :

```
EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>  myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname);
```

There is no error anymore now but this new line makes it keep adding the new tag all the time nonstop when I click the button "Remove Tag" it's adding the tag over again because of this new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (not tested) that your getting the error because you are changing the layout of the inspector while its trying to render. I guess myTarget.AddnewTag/delete adds or removes elements to be rendered in the custom inspector correct?

If you want to do that you can use EditorApplication.delayCall for that. Its a Delegate which is called once after all inspectors update.

```
 public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    

    DrawDefaultInspector();
    TagsAndLayers myTarget = (TagsAndLayers)target;

    tagname = EditorGUILayout.TextField("", tagname);

    if (tagname == "" || tagname == null)
    {
        GUI.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button("Create Tag"))
    {
         EditorApplication.delayCall += () => {myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname)};
    }

    if (GUILayout.Button("Remove Tag"))
    {
         EditorApplication.delayCall += () => {myTarget.DeleteTag(tagname)};
    }

    GUILayout.Space(50);

    layername = EditorGUILayout.TextField("", layername);

    if(layername == "" || layername == null)
    {
        GUI.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button("Create Layer"))
    {
        EditorApplication.delayCall += () => { myTarget.AddNewLayer(layername)};
    }

    if (GUILayout.Button("Remove Layer"))
    {
         EditorApplication.delayCall += () => {myTarget.DeleteLayer(layername)};
    }
}
```

}

It lets the inspector render the data it had and on the next frame the new stuff. Just add any calls that would change the look of the inspector by that to avoid the issue. The delegate is automatically cleaned so you don't need to minus or anything.

Comment: but all the places I'm doing myTarget.AddNew are inside GUILayout.Button then why it's trying to render ? and in your  solution I added the line EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>  myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname); after the line TagsAndLayers myTarget = (TagsAndLayers)target; but what do I do now with the rest of the code or to leave it this way ?

Comment: That whole function is there to change the way the editor is rendered. When you add GUILayout.Button it trys to render a button etc... The problem comes from the editor rendering something like a list/array in a previous step (prob in draw default inspector) and then in the same render call you modify that list which would change how it is displayed. The line of code I wrote should replace anywhere you modify the list. Like inside the if guibutton. Basically you tell unity to change the list in the next inspector frame. Both add /delete functions should use that for both lists.

Comment: Now there is no error but now it's adding all the time the new tag this line EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>  myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname); inside the OnInspectorGUI() is being called all the time and keep adding new tag even if I removed the tag with the remove button.

Comment: I update my question with the code how it is after the changes after adding the new line in your solution.

Comment: no no that line should only be on button pressed ;).  In your code you have 4 places were you either add or delete a tag/layer. The only additions to your original code should be wrapping all of them with the delegate i.e. if (GUILayout.Button("Create tag"))
{ myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname); } becomes if (GUILayout.Button("Create tag"))
{ EditorApplication.delayCall += () => { myTarget.AddNewTag(tagname);} }